# Best way to get all combinations of root array with other n children arrays

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, tree, combinations

I'm working on some path finding stuff and ran into an issues I need help with. I have an
array 'root' and I need compare with other arrays and find all combinations with each 'root' element

The only way I know how to do it would be something like this:

```
 function getAllCombinationsArray(){
    $return = array();

    $root = array( 1=>'cat1', 2=>'cat2', 3=>'cat3' );
    $child_1 = array( 1=>'sub_cat1', 2=>'sub_cat2', 3=>'sub_cat3' );
    $child_2 = array( 1=>'sub_sub_cat1', 2=>'sub_sub_cat2', 3=>'sub_sub_cat3' );

    foreach($root as $fk => $fv){
        foreach($child_1 as $ck => $cv){
            $cid = $fk.'_'.$ck;
            $cname = $fv.' -> '.$cv;
            foreach($child_2 as $ck2 => $cv2){
                $id = $cid.'_'.$ck2;
                $name = $cname.' -> '.$cv2;
                $return[$id] = $name;
            }
        }
    }
    return $return;         
}

print_r(getAllCombinationsArray());
```

The Output is:

```
Array
(
      [1_1_1] => cat1 -> sub_cat1 -> sub_sub_cat1
      [1_1_2] => cat1 -> sub_cat1 -> sub_sub_cat2
      [1_1_3] => cat1 -> sub_cat1 -> sub_sub_cat3
      [1_2_1] => cat1 -> sub_cat2 -> sub_sub_cat1
      [1_2_2] => cat1 -> sub_cat2 -> sub_sub_cat2
      [1_2_3] => cat1 -> sub_cat2 -> sub_sub_cat3
      [1_3_1] => cat1 -> sub_cat3 -> sub_sub_cat1
      [1_3_2] => cat1 -> sub_cat3 -> sub_sub_cat2
      [1_3_3] => cat1 -> sub_cat3 -> sub_sub_cat3
      [2_1_1] => cat2 -> sub_cat1 -> sub_sub_cat1
      [2_1_2] => cat2 -> sub_cat1 -> sub_sub_cat2
      [2_1_3] => cat2 -> sub_cat1 -> sub_sub_cat3
      [2_2_1] => cat2 -> sub_cat2 -> sub_sub_cat1
      [2_2_2] => cat2 -> sub_cat2 -> sub_sub_cat2
      [2_2_3] => cat2 -> sub_cat2 -> sub_sub_cat3
      [2_3_1] => cat2 -> sub_cat3 -> sub_sub_cat1
      [2_3_2] => cat2 -> sub_cat3 -> sub_sub_cat2
      [2_3_3] => cat2 -> sub_cat3 -> sub_sub_cat3
      [3_1_1] => cat3 -> sub_cat1 -> sub_sub_cat1
      [3_1_2] => cat3 -> sub_cat1 -> sub_sub_cat2
      [3_1_3] => cat3 -> sub_cat1 -> sub_sub_cat3
      [3_2_1] => cat3 -> sub_cat2 -> sub_sub_cat1
      [3_2_2] => cat3 -> sub_cat2 -> sub_sub_cat2
      [3_2_3] => cat3 -> sub_cat2 -> sub_sub_cat3
      [3_3_1] => cat3 -> sub_cat3 -> sub_sub_cat1
      [3_3_2] => cat3 -> sub_cat3 -> sub_sub_cat2
      [3_3_3] => cat3 -> sub_cat3 -> sub_sub_cat3
)
```

But this is very inefficient when I have multi children arrays with multi values associated.

Eg.:

If I have one root array with 3 elements and 4 other children arrays with 1,36,21 and 2 elements respectively my number of total combinations is 3*1*36*21*2 = 4536. When I execute the function above I have waiting for more than 5 minutes. Please I hope for you help to get more efficiency in my algorithm.

Comment: It sounds like what you're describing is an inherently exponential problem (like Travelling Salesman).  Even a relatively small data set could potentially generate a huge amount of results and bigger data sets will only make the problem worse

Comment: Look up P=NP, solve that and you can solve your problem.  You will ALSO break every form of encryption and gain a sizable bounty on your head by most national super-powers.  In the end, I think you are solving the wrong problem, it seems like your data-set is "weird", and maybe if you approached it from a different angle you would have better luck.